# Finding a method's declaring type

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

Given a MethodDeclarationSyntax object how can I find out the method's declaring type?

My actual problem is that I need to figure it out whether the referenced method is implementing an interface method or not.

For instance, given the code bellow, if I have a MethodDeclarationSyntax for the *Dispose()* method, how can conclude it is the implementation of the IDisposable.Dispose()?

```
using System;
abstract class InterfaceImplementation : IDisposable
{
    public abstract void Dispose();
}
```

I've tried to get the method's declaring type (and check the type) with no success (Parent property gives me back InterfaceImplementation class).

I also have tried to grab the semantic symbol for the method:

```
var methodSymbol = (MethodSymbol) semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(methodDeclaration);
```

but could not spot anything that could help me.

Ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you have the method symbol, you can ask if a given method is implementing an interface method within a given type. The code is fairly simple:

```cs
MethodSymbol method = ...;
TypeSymbol type = method.ContainingType;
MethodSymbol disposeMethod = (MethodSymbol)c.GetSpecialType(SpecialType.System_IDisposable).GetMembers("Dispose").Single();
bool isDisposeMethod = method.Equals(type.FindImplementationForInterfaceMember(disposeMethod));
```

It's important to note this assumes the type that contains the Dispose method is the type that states it implements IDisposable. In C#, it's possible for a method to implement an interface method that's only stated on a derived type. More concretely, if you ommtted the ": IDisposable" on your code above, and had a derived type of InterfaceImplementation that was IDisposable, that Dispose() method can still implement it.

Comment: I would use the `==` operator instead of `Equals()` here, because `FindImplementationForInterfaceMember()` can return `null`. Or at least write the `Equals()` the other way around.

Comment: @svick: good point on swapping the Equals ordering. My use of Equals is not by accident, as an important habit we've developed on the Roslyn team: using == will work fine as long as you're using the language-specific types only. If you had two IMethodSymbols, you *must* use Equals as == isn't overloaded in that case.

Comment: @Jason I am afraid this will not help me since it assumes I know what methods I need to check against (in your code, you grab a reference to Dispose() method symbol and compare against that) which is not the case. Of course I can check the base class/interfaces  recursively (until I reach object) but I'll would expect that MethodSymbol class could provide me this information directly.

Comment: A MethodSymbol does not provide this, but as Kevin pointed out, it cannot. A method can be implementing an interface even if that interface is not stated in the base type chain of the type. The only question that can be answered is "given this set of classes, does this method Foo() implement an interface method in any of them". Roslyn can't know all the classes in the world, so MethodSymbol can't provide it directly without being fed a bunch of extra information.

Comment: One thing you didn't mention in your original question is what you plan on doing once you know a given method implements an interface. If you don't mind me asking, what is your ultimate goal here? Perhaps a better understanding of your scenario could help us craft a better API here.

Comment: @Jason I am playing with IL generation from C# source code (I want to learn a little more about IL and play with Roslyn). My actual problem is that I am visiting a method definition and need to decide which modifiers/flags to set in the IL (NewSlot, Virtual, Final, etc). To do that I need to know (among other things) whether the method is defined in an interface. Since I have all required assemblies being referenced , I'd assume that Rolsyn could provide this information for me.

Comment: So I chatted a bit with one of the compiler devs on how they handle emitting of interface methods in this case. His recommendation was that when you're emitting an interface method, you should emit just the method as you would as if it wasn't an interface method, and then emit the interface implementations separately which may have a stub method as appropriate.

Comment: It's really not clear in the answer what `c` ought to be in this case and where to get it. Should mention that it's the compilation.

Answer (score 5):

The syntax types (like `MethodDeclarationSyntax`) operate *only* on the syntactic level. At this level, there is no knowledge whether the method `Dispose` implements `IDisposable`. That's because you don't know yet what methods `IDisposable` has. What's more, you don't even know whether `IDisposable` exists, whether it's a class or interface, or what is its full name. (Is it `System.IDisposable`? Or `MyNamespace.IDisposable`?)

To get information like that, you need to get to the semantic level, as you guessed.

I didn't find any way to get from a method to the interface directly, unless it's an explicit interface implementation (EDIT: that's because it's not always possible, see Kevin's comment). But you can get from a type to the implementation of some specific interface method.

So, if you want to find out that a certain `MethodSymbol` implements `IDisposable.Dispose()`, you could do something like:

```cs
SyntaxTree unit = SyntaxTree.ParseCompilationUnit(code);

MethodDeclarationSyntax method = …;

var compilation = Compilation.Create("test")
    .AddReferences(new AssemblyFileReference(typeof(object).Assembly.Location))
    .AddSyntaxTrees(unit);

SemanticModel model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(unit);

MethodSymbol methodSymbol = (MethodSymbol)model.GetDeclaredSymbol(method);

var typeSymbol = methodSymbol.ContainingType;

var idisposableDisposeSymbol = model.BindExpression(
    0, Syntax.ParseExpression("System.IDisposable.Dispose()")).Symbol;

var implementation = typeSymbol.FindImplementationForInterfaceMember(
    idisposableDisposeSymbol);

bool methodImplementsDispose = methodSymbol == implementation;
```

Comment: The reason you can't do this from the method is that sometimes you can't tell.  If you have `class Base { public void Dispose() } class Derived : Base, IDisposable { }` then "Dispose" is the implementation _if you have an instance of Derived_, but not if you have an instance of Base...

Comment: Hmm, I didn't realize that's even possible, interesting.